# Help for wiring a bathroom exhaust fan

Tags: electrical

[image]I have a NuTone model QTN130LE1 ventilation fan/light. I have 2 switches on the wall. One is for the light,the other is for the fan.im not sure how to wire it up properly. I don't think I can use the nightlight because I don't have consistent power to the unit,unless a switch is on. I have a black,white,red and a bare ground wire for power. From what I can see,the red wire is coming from the fan switch.  The unit has a green,taped red and white,taped white and blue,and a taped together black and white wires. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do the installation instructions say to do?

Comment: I can't post a pic, because its too big. Wiring diagram is a little confusing

Comment: Take a picture of the instructions, post it to imgur, paste the link in a comment and someone will embed it for you.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the diagram

Comment: With the wires being taped for color you may have conduit and may be able to pull a new wire for the night light. ??  A photo of the wiring would clear this up.

Answer (score 1):

Your green wire from the fan gets connected to the bare copper wire from your ceiling box. Then connect the white wire taped with the blue to the white wire taped to the black to the white wire from your ceiling box. Then connect the red wire from your switch to the black wire from your fan and connect the blue wire from your fan light to the black wire coming from your other switch.  The remaining red and white wires from your fan fixture are for the night light which you would need another switch to operate it

Comment: Does the grounds hook up to the ground screw on unit?

Comment: @ChrisHill  Yes it does.

Comment: Awesome, ty so much